# how to delete object from the array of objects in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

> I have notes nested in userSchema I am trying to delete one object by _id but deleteOne is removing the whole user object so how can I can delete the one with _id

```
const keeperSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    noteName:String,
    noteContent:String,
    })

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String,
    notes:[keeperSchema]
    })

app.post("/delete",(req,res)=>{
    const id=req.body.id
    const email=req.body.email
    console.log(id)

    Keeper.deleteOne({"notes._id":id}).then(()=>{               
        Keeper.find({email:email},(err,results)=>{
            if(results){
                console.log(results)
           }
        })
    })

   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like so:

```
  userModel.updateOne({_id: idofUser}, {$pull: {notes: {_id: idofnote}}})
```

you should query on your `userModel` because you want to pull an element from keeper array which is stored in `user` so you have to determine from which user you want to delete your note thats why you need to have the id of user. if you want to delete a specific note from all of the users just clear your condition like so:

```
  userModel.updateMany({}, {$pull: {notes: {_id: idofnote}}})
```